# Modifying 形容動詞 (ナ adjectives) with verb phrases

Tags: grammar, syntax, adjectives, na-adjectives

In my textbook, the following phrase:

> **子どもたちが話している**にぎやかな声

is derived from the following example sentence:

> にぎやかな声で子どもたちが話している。

It is the phrase that confuses me. It appears to me that the section in bold is modifying にぎやか, and if this is indeed the case, I do not understand the meaning of this construct.

I would appreciate help understanding this phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What to do you think about this parsing: (子どもたちが話している)(にぎやかな声). The verb phrase modifies にぎやかな声 as a whole.

---

**EDIT**:
The て form and 連体節 (modifying with a verb phrase) doesn't serve the same purpose. て tends to stream-line (one things after the other) whereas 連体節 modifies the things that follows.

(子どもたちが話していて)(にぎやかな声), the parenthesis can't be placed like that. At most, you can insert a comma : 子どもたちが話していて、にぎやかな声(…) but it doesn't really make sense if you don't complete the … part.

In (あったかくて) (おいしい料理), here again parenthesis can't be like that. あったかくて、おいしい料理 (The food is warm and and it is good/delicious) (another way to understand it would be: The food is warm and (because of that) it is good/delicious)

More information on how to parse sentence can be found in Appendix 8 of the book "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar".
And if you're brave enough 連体節 are discussed in details [here](http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/56rentaisetu.html) ;) (beware EUC-JP encoding)

Comment: That would make sense. However, I was not aware that that was valid Japanese. I thought you had to conjugate successive modifier phrases into a て form, as in (あったかくて) (おいしい料理).

Then again, (子どもたちが話していて)(にぎやかな声) does appear odd.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks! I can't view either source easily, but I guess (あったかい) (おいしい料理) would be valid after all?